# Compile with a windows plugin.dll for a linux plateform UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, plugins

I'm working for someone that develop a game on Windows with Unity.
What's happening if I'm building for him a windows plugin (.dll format) and then that he tries to compile the game for linux?

A .dll can't be read from unix systems, and Unity for windows can't load .so plugins, so what's the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need seperate native plugins for each platform, it has always been the case, unless the plugin is Managed Code / c#, you need to provide windows,mac, linux, android, ios, xbox etc